# API, Modes, and their Short-Names

Tags: neovim

I'm using `nvim_get_mode` to get the current mode of Neovim for a Rust-based plugin that I'm working on. However, a cursory look through Neovim's docs doesn't show a comprehensive list of the editor's possible modes and their mapped shortnames. Is there any place where I can find a list of modes and their shortnames for use?

Comment: At least in vim, it’s document with the `mode()` function... I would be surprised if it wasn’t documented with the function?

Comment: Actually, there's a link to `:h mode()` right in the corresponding help topic (`:h nvim_get_mode()`). Just move the cursor over it and press `C-]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@Matt confirms in the comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22320/api-modes-and-their-short-names#comment40428_22320), it is documented at `mode()`:

```
           n        Normal, Terminal-Normal
           no       Operator-pending
           nov      Operator-pending (forced characterwise |o_v|)
           noV      Operator-pending (forced linewise |o_V|)
           noCTRL-V Operator-pending (forced blockwise |o_CTRL-V|);
                CTRL-V is one character
           niI      Normal using |i_CTRL-O| in |Insert-mode|
           niR      Normal using |i_CTRL-O| in |Replace-mode|
           niV      Normal using |i_CTRL-O| in |Virtual-Replace-mode|
           v        Visual by character
           V        Visual by line
           CTRL-V   Visual blockwise
           s        Select by character
           S        Select by line
           CTRL-S   Select blockwise
           i        Insert
           ic       Insert mode completion |compl-generic|
           ix       Insert mode |i_CTRL-X| completion
           R        Replace |R|
           Rc       Replace mode completion |compl-generic|
           Rv       Virtual Replace |gR|
           Rx       Replace mode |i_CTRL-X| completion
           c        Command-line editing
           cv       Vim Ex mode |gQ|
           ce       Normal Ex mode |Q|
           r        Hit-enter prompt
           rm       The -- more -- prompt
           r?       A |:confirm| query of some sort
           !        Shell or external command is executing
           t        Terminal-Job mode: keys go to the job
```

Comment: Ah, much appreciated!